# grouping duplicate rows while the original sort remains intact

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, grouping

Say I have Account Numbers, Sub-account Numbers and values in a google spreadsheet where there can be *duplicate* Account Numbers with different sub-acc numbers:

```
acc no / sub acc no / val
2      /     5      /  6
3      /     10     /  8
4      /     9      /  2
2      /     14     /  1
```

After I sort the whole sheet by the third column, values, it's gonna look like this:

```
acc no / sub acc no / val
3      /     10     /  8
2      /     5      /  6
4      /     9      /  2
2      /     14     /  1
```

So, what I want to do is to **group** all meters under the same accounts while having the original sort remain intact:

```
acc no / sub acc no / val
3      /     10     /  8
2      /     5      /  6
2      /     14     /  1
4      /     9     /  2
```

Seems like after sorting it by values, I need a script that loops through the account No column, for each cell it will check the remaining account numbers, and if there's a matching duplicate one, it's gonna get moved up.

This is what I could come up with so far:

```
function group(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // find how many accounts we have 
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  for (var i = 0; i < Alast-2; i++) {
    if(Avals[i].toString() == Avals[i+1].toString()){
      continue;
    }
    for (var j = i+2; j < Alast; j++){
      if(Avals[i].toString() == Avals[j].toString()){
        //move
        break;
      }
    }   
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a script. What have you tried? I recommend writing a sort function for a Javascript array: Here's the [reference page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Arrays that come from reading the values on a google sheet are "2D", e.g. `[ [r1c1, r1c2, ... r1cN], [r2c1, r2c2, ...r2cN], ... [rNc1, ... rNcN] ]` See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @tehhowch I know I need a script but I haven't tried anything since I have no experience in google apps script. Sorry.

Comment: You are expected to make an effort. This likely requires you to complete a tutorial or 3, or even take an introductory programming course.

Comment: @tehhowch I don't even have a lot of programming experience, I didn't know that this platform only helped people who know programming but got stuck.

Comment: You don't have a specific question. You have a request for work to be done for you. Those are very different.

Comment: @tehhowch I added my code but couldn't figure out how to move the cell

Comment: The easiest solution is to write your own sorting object (if using `Range#sort`) or comparator function (if using `Array#sort`), rather than try to custom-craft code that rearranges cells. You could also record and tweak a [Macro](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros) to first sort by the value column, and then the column with the account numbers.

Comment: @I'-'I exactly yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample script. Untested. Assumes Sheet is already sorted by C column.

```
function group(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  // find how many accounts we have 
  //get A2:C range& values
  var rng = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,3);
  var val = rng.getValues();
  var data =[];//output array
  var k=0; //data array new row count
  //loop through existing rows
  for(i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    //if A is not empty, new k row data array = original row.
    if (val[i][0]) { //value check
      data[k] = val[i];
      k++; //increment k to next row
    //Loop through rows after current row to find next  similar A value,if any
    for(j=i+1;j<val.length;j++) { 
      if (val[i][0] == val[j][0]) { //if one of the folllowing row's A value is == current A value
        data[k] =val[j].slice(0); //new k data array = j row
        k++; //increment k
        val[j][0] =''; //set  the duplicate  j row's A value to null to skip during value check 
      }
    }
   }
  }
//Logger.log(data);
sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: ``val`` of ``val.setValues(data)`` is the array. So how about modifying like ``var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,3); var val = range.getValues();``, ``range.setValues(data);``. Or ``sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1,3).setValues(data)``?

Comment: I get this error: ""Incorrect range height, was 4 but should be 9"", thank you! 

This is the log: [18-04-26 10:24:08:317 EDT] [[Acc3, 2.0, 9.0], [Acc2, 1.0, 7.0], [, 2.0, 3.0], [Acc1, 1.0, 5.0]]

Comment: @I'-'I wow yes this works. thank you so much. But in the row that gets moved up, the account no field is blank after moving. Also, can you tell me how do I do this so no matter how many rows there are, it does the same thing? thank you!

Comment: @I'-'I Thank you so much, this so much better than my way of doing it: after setting all the values, I filled the blank ones by copying from one upper cell which was waaay slow. Thanks again!

Comment: @I'-'I I already figured that out by changing rng to sheet.getDataRange() instead. Thank you!